# I try to call .hide() after 1sec (using setTimeout), but it's executed directly, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I try to hide a subnavigation when mouseout (second function in .hover()) after 1sec and for that I using setTimeout. I need the this variable in the inner function of setTimeout, so I try it like this:

```
jQuery(".topnav > ul > li").hover(function() {
        jQuery("ul.topnavsub").hide();
        jQuery(this).find("ul.topnavsub").show();
    }, function() {
        var t = setTimeout((function(that){jQuery(that).find("ul.topnavsub").hide(); console.log(that);})(this), 1000);
    });
```

This works but with no delay. 1. Why is there not a 1000milisec deplay and 2. How would I have to do that it works correctly?

If I get this working I want to add: when entering the subnav in that 1000milisec, the setTimeout stops, so that the nav does not get hidden. That's what I have but I couldn't test it cause the hole setTimeout-thing don't work:

```
jQuery(".topnav > nav > ul > li").hover(function() {
    jQuery("ul.topnavsub").off();
    jQuery("ul.topnavsub").hide();
    jQuery(this).find("ul.topnavsub").show();
}, function() {
    var t = setTimeout((function(that){jQuery(that).find("ul.topnavsub").hide(); console.log(that);})(this), 1000);
    jQuery(this).find("ul.topnavsub").on("mouseenter", function() {
        clearTimeout(t);
        jQuery(this).off();
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the (this) doing at the end of the function?  It looks like it's self-invoking the function.

Answer (score 0):

The convoluted way :

```
var t = setTimeout((function(that){ return function(){
    jQuery(that).find("ul.topnavsub").hide();
    console.log(that);
  }
})(this), 1000);
```

The less-cool-but-still-works-(-and-is-probably-more-readable-) way :

```
var that = this;
var t = setTimeout(function(){ 
    jQuery(that).find("ul.topnavsub").hide();
    console.log(that);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The anonymous function is being self executed.

```
var t = setTimeout((function(that){
        jQuery(that).find("ul.topnavsub").hide(); 
        console.log(that);
    })(this),  //(this) is self executing
    1000);
});
```

Alternative:

```
var that = this;
var t = setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery(that).find("ul.topnavsub").hide(); 
        console.log(that);
    },1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you executing a function and pass undefined to setTimeout

```
var t = setTimeout((function(that){
   jQuery(that).find("ul.topnavsub").hide();
   console.log(that);
})(this), 1000);
```

just remove `(this)` from the end of the function

```
var self = this;
var t = setTimeout(function(){
   jQuery(self).find("ul.topnavsub").hide();
   console.log(self);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: the function passed to setTimeout won't receive any argument. When excuting the function, `that` will be undefined.